# compiling the 2.6.0 kernel on slackware

Tags: linux-kernel, slackware

out of sheer curiosity I tried compiling a 2.6.0 kernel on my slackware machine.

```
root@darkstar:/home/linux-2.6.0# uname -a
Linux darkstar 2.6.37.6-smp #2 SMP Sat Apr 9 23:39:07 CDT 2011 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

When I try compiling I get :-

```
root@darkstar:/home/linux-2.6.0# make menuconfig                                                                                         
  HOSTCC  scripts/fixdep
scripts/fixdep.c: In function 'traps':
scripts/fixdep.c:359:2: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
scripts/fixdep.c:361:4: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/mconf.o
scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:91:21: error: static declaration of 'current_menu' follows non-static declaration
scripts/kconfig/lkc.h:63:21: note: previous declaration of 'current_menu' was here
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf.o] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Some hints on what im doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you doing this to start with?

Typically, you download the latest kernel from kernel.org, copy the tarball to /usr/src, then:

```
 1. tar -zxvvf linux-2.6.xxxx.tar.gz
 2. ln -nsf linux-2.6.xxxx linux   # ie: Update the "/usr/src/linux" symbolic link to
                                   #   point to the new kernel source directory
 3. make menuconfig                # or make xconfig
 4. make modules                   # Build the kernel modules
 5. make modules_install           # Install the previously built modules for the
                                   #   new kernel
 6. make bzImage                   # Create the boot image
```

At this point, **DO NOT** run `make install`. Most guides say to do this, but this is WRONG! Instead, copy the newly created bzImage file to /boot (ie: `find -name bzImage /usr/src/linux`, then `cp` to `/boot`), then edit your LILO configuration file (edit `/etc/lilo.conf`, and when done, run `lilo`), then reboot your system (ie: `init 6` or `shutdown -r now`), and try out the new kernel.

The whole point of skipping the `make install` step is because it overwrites/replaces your existing kernel. The steps I described above allow you to have the new kernel and your existing kernel both installed and runnable in parallel. If the new kernel is broken or your left out an important option, you can still fall back to your existing stable/working kernel without the need for a boot/recovery CD/DVD.

Comment: Could you also include in the answer how to make the bootloader to show different kernels for sometime. It just skips as it stays for very little time

Comment: It depends on whether you are using LILO or GRUB. Slackware uses lilo by default, so all you have to do is edit </etc/lilo.conf> (you should be able to duplicate an existing line in the file, the syntax is not difficult to understand). Once you've saved the updated <lilo.conf> file, just run the <lilo> command. If it completes without critical/fatal errors, you are all set. :) 

<http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lilo-cfg.html>

Comment: I am using grub2 from ubuntu. could you tell for that too if possible. Thanks

Comment: I think you can just edit the bootloader menu via a GUI tool in Ubuntu. I haven't much familiarity with grub. You should probably search for it here or on google.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall well i think you are missing the ncurses libraries. Those are needed to create the interface with menuconfig.

Try a to do a make xconfig from an X session and see if it works.

if that is the case then the ncurses libs are definitely missing.

check with:

```
ls /var/log/packages/ncurses*
```

to see if installed